# By-reference / by-pointer in assembly code

Tags: c++, assembly, reference, x86, g++

I wanted to see how calling by-reference differs from by-pointer in C++.
However, the g++ compiler (using -O0 -S) produces identical code.
I tried 'tricking' the compiler in producing some sort of difference using all sorts of contrived constructs, but it seems more clever than I am.
Is there a way into turning off all cleverness in gcc so I can understand the implementation of references in assembly?

[Edit]

```
/* Testing assembly representation of ref/pointer/by-value parameters */

int byRef(int &value, int value2) {
    value = value2;
    return value;
}

int byPtr(int * value, int value2) {
    *value = value2;
    return *value;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int value = 5;
    byRef(value, value);
    byPtr(&value, value);
}


call    ___main
movl    $5, -4(%ebp)
movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
leal    -4(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    __Z5byRefRii
movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
leal    -4(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    __Z5byPtrPii
movl    $0, %eax
```

No difference here either.. is there an easy way to trigger the semantic reuse?

Comment: I doubt you're going to find a way to get g++ to generate different code for references and pointer as references are more or less just pointers with a different syntax.

Comment: There's no difference between accessing a pointer and a reference at assembly level.

Comment: "turning off all cleverness in gcc so I can understand __the__ implementation of references in assembly" - you're presuming that there is precisely one implementation. There's no foundation for that belief.

Comment: Related: [How does assembly do parameter passing: by value, reference, pointer for different types/arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19858980)

Answer (score 6):

There is not much more to understand, really.

Reference *are* pointers, **and** references *are not* pointers.

More correctly, references are of course *not pointers at all*, they are *aliases*. Which means that semantically, they are the same variable, just under a different name. This means that the compiler can often do clever renaming tricks to entirely optimize passing the references at all.

Sometimes, it *still* has to pass the reference somehow, and then that usually happens via a pointer (this is not a requirement, but happens to be the one technique that fits). The only observable difference to a pointer, under the hood, will be that a reference can't be null, and the compiler knows that (though, if you are malicious enough, you *can* create a null reference).

Comment: Ok, so I guess there must be an easy a way to cause a difference in generated code with the semantic hints provided by references (or the lack thereof)?

Comment: Usually, references do need to be passed on non-inlined function calls, and usually they will be entirely eleminated if function calls are inlined. In that case, they are just aliases, the same, identical variable under a different name, used in a different scope. Thus, enforcing or preventing inlining will likely cause you to see that difference. But like already pointed out, the only difference is "pointer or no pointer", there is no additional magic in them.

Comment: You can't actually create a null reference. You can dereference a null pointer then assign a reference to that result. . .but that operation is already undefined by definition. . . Either way, the reference refers to something, assuming your compiler's response to dereferencing a null pointer isn't to crash the program or anything else along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is nothing more to it. The reference is another name, an alias, for some object that exists elsewhere.

You have now learned that the reference, in this case, is implemented using the address of the object it refers to (as an implementation detail). The language doesn't say how this should work, just what the effects are.

Using the object's address seems like a simple solution, and is of course what practically every implementation use.

Comment: No, I don't know anyone who does it differently. On the other hand, I have not used every compiler either. And on this site, as soon as you write "never" or "always" someone has a different example.

Comment: You're just guaranteed behavior of a reference. That many compilers happen to implement it (in some cases) with pointers, is just a coincidence. There's no way for you to actually convert from a pointer to a reference and you can't get a reference to a reference so it really doesn't matter how it's implemented.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way into turning off all cleverness in gcc so I can understand the implementation of references in assembly?

Apparently not. Put differently: you *are* already seeing it: pass by reference is usually implemented via pointers.

Comment: We all know reference shares the same address of which object its referring to but I think reference should take some space in stack as well, do you think there is anyway of getting that address (the apparaent way of using pointer to reference is illegal)?

Comment: @Gob00st If you have a reference to a local variable, it will just be an alias, it won’t consume any stack space at all. If it is an argument then it will consume stack space but there is no safe way to retrieve it. You could calculate backwards from the address of a locally declared variable, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the **semantic** context!

References are pointers in the context of the generated binary code.

References are references only in the translation phase from C++ to ASM.

The C++ standard does not tell compiler writers how to implement their compilers. But practically, there is no other convenient way of implementing references in compilers.

Answer (score 2):

You should to consider two level of semantics - C++ and ASM.
ASM semantics doesn't contain references, so references and pointers are translated to pointers (it is already mentioned in other answers).

However probably there is a difference in translation rules. Try to play with something like:

```
int i = 7;
int * pi = i;
int & ri = i;

int &* rpi = pi;
int *& pri = &ri;
```

to break its equivalence. And also try to check [ARM] for detailed description of references and pointers. I'm not sure if my answer will help you, but hope so. Please feed back if you find counterexample. I'm interested too.